Map values of one column to another based on conditional
I'm trying to parse a nested JSON using pandas and currently have below example structure.
input = {'id': ['uid1', 'uid2'],
     'code': ['A:D;X:X;Y:E;R:Name;P:3;R:Name2;P:1;Z:3', 'B:1,B:2,R:SomeName,P:1,R:SomeName_Z,P:0,M:1,M:3'], 
     'values': [';;;;1.0;2.0;3.0;;;0.5;0.1;1.5;;;', ';;;1.5;1.1;1.4;;;4.1;3.2;3.3;;;;'],
     'reference': [['Name', 'Name2'], ['SomeName', 'SomeName_Z']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=input, index=[0, 1])


     id                                             code                            values               reference
0  uid1           A:D;X:X;Y:E;R:Name;P:3;R:Name2;P:1;Z:3  ;;;;1.0;2.0;3.0;;;0.5;0.1;1.5;;;           [Name, Name2]
1  uid2  B:1,B:2,R:SomeName,P:1,R:SomeName_Z,P:0,M:1,M:3  ;;;1.5;1.1;1.4;;;4.1;3.2;3.3;;;;  [SomeName, SomeName_Z]

I'm stuck at a point where I need to map each reference to 3 values. The logic to find those 3 values is as follows:

Items in code/values columns are separated by ;. Each item in code will have one value in values column.
If there is any R: in code column and the next item is P: then that P: will have 4 values in the values column, first 3 values will be decimals and the 4th one will be empty. We need to assign these 3 values to given R: and put them under first, second, third columns.

Expected:
     id                                             code                            values   reference first second third
0  uid1           A:D;X:X;Y:E;R:Name;P:3;R:Name2;P:1;Z:3  ;;;;1.0;2.0;3.0;;;0.5;0.1;1.5;;;        Name   1.0    2.0   3.0
1  uid1           A:D;X:X;Y:E;R:Name;P:3;R:Name2;P:1;Z:3  ;;;;1.0;2.0;3.0;;;0.5;0.1;1.5;;;       Name2   0.5    0.1   1.5
2  uid2  B:1,B:2,R:SomeName,P:1,R:SomeName_Z,P:0,M:1,M:3  ;;;1.5;1.1;1.4;;;4.1;3.2;3.3;;;;    SomeName   1.5    1.1   1.4
3  uid2  B:1,B:2,R:SomeName,P:1,R:SomeName_Z,P:0,M:1,M:3  ;;;1.5;1.1;1.4;;;4.1;3.2;3.3;;;;  SomeName_Z   4.1    3.2   3.3


It can be done by processing one row at a time, while parsing the code and values fields and collecting the new rows into a separate list.
import pandas as pd

input_data = {
    'id': ['uid1', 'uid2'],
    'code': ['A:D;X:X;Y:E;R:Name;P:3;R:Name2;P:1;Z:3', 'B:1;B:2;R:SomeName;P:1;R:SomeName_Z;P:0;M:1;M:3'], 
    'values': [';;;;1.0;2.0;3.0;;;0.5;0.1;1.5;;;', ';;;1.5;1.1;1.4;;;4.1;3.2;3.3;;;;'],
    'reference': [['Name', 'Name2'], ['SomeName', 'SomeName_Z']]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=input_data, index=[0, 1])

# The final set of rows get added here
expanded_rows = []

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    code_parts = row['code'].split(';')
    value_parts = row['values'].split(';')
    references = row['reference']
    
    code_index, values_index = 0, 0
    while code_index < len(code_parts):
        row_added = False
        if code_parts[code_index].startswith('R:'):
            reference_name = code_parts[code_index].split(':')[1]
            if code_index + 1 < len(code_parts) and code_parts[code_index + 1].startswith('P:'):
                # At this point, we can go ahead and read the 3 values after skipping the current value
                # (reading from values_index+1 because we want 3 values for the "P:" and we're still at the "R:")
                values = value_parts[values_index+1:values_index+4]
                if len(values) == 3:
                    expanded_rows.append({
                        'id': row['id'],
                        'code': row['code'],
                        'values': row['values'],
                        'reference': reference_name,
                        'first': values[0],
                        'second': values[1],
                        'third': values[2]
                    })
                row_added = True
        if not row_added:
            # If we didn't find a "R:", "P:" sequence, we did not add a new row, so 
            # just advance each index by one
            code_index += 1
            values_index += 1
        else:
            # We added a new row. This means we have to skip the code_index past "R:" and "P:"
            # And we have to skip the values_index 5 steps ahead (1 past the current index + 4 values associated with the "P:")
            code_index += 2
            values_index += 5

expanded_df = pd.DataFrame(expanded_rows)

print(expanded_df)


Output
  id                                            code                           values  reference first second third
uid1          A:D;X:X;Y:E;R:Name;P:3;R:Name2;P:1;Z:3 ;;;;1.0;2.0;3.0;;;0.5;0.1;1.5;;;       Name   1.0    2.0   3.0
uid1          A:D;X:X;Y:E;R:Name;P:3;R:Name2;P:1;Z:3 ;;;;1.0;2.0;3.0;;;0.5;0.1;1.5;;;      Name2   0.5    0.1   1.5
uid2 B:1;B:2;R:SomeName;P:1;R:SomeName_Z;P:0;M:1;M:3 ;;;1.5;1.1;1.4;;;4.1;3.2;3.3;;;;   SomeName   1.5    1.1   1.4
uid2 B:1;B:2;R:SomeName;P:1;R:SomeName_Z;P:0;M:1;M:3 ;;;1.5;1.1;1.4;;;4.1;3.2;3.3;;;; SomeName_Z   4.1    3.2   3.3


The code did get a little hairy due to the complex business logic involved.

Did this answer the question?

Yes, thank you. Only once slight change required is that the df may have some rows for which there's no code where R: is followed by P:. Those rows are getting skipped in expanded_df. I want to put null in first, second, third for those rows yet still split in multiple row i.e. if row has 2 references then create 2 rows one for each reference.
